# Azure AD B2C certificate pinning

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to make certificate pinning work on mobile app for azure ad b2c, which uses login.microsoftonline.com domain, and I'm wondering how I could do it. The current certificate expires 25.9.2020 and I would need to know what is the next one or do they rotate it so that the public key stays the same?

I have found a repository of Microsoft CA certificates (https://www.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/cps/default.htm) but I guess I cannot make the certificate pinning to those since they are used in all azure services.

**Edit:**

I have decided work around the problem and I just whitelist the login domain.